# What to do about my 11-month-old refusing all types of fluid including breast milk?

Tags: infant, breastfeeding

My child is one in July. He was brilliantly breastfeeding since birth, exclusively, up until 3 weeks ago, when he started biting. I said no and pulled away. He would cry and I would eventually give in. He then carried on drinking and then after a minute bite again but pull too!

5 days ago, the same thing happened: as he pulled I said no etc. but this time when I offered **he** refused, pushing me away. He has since pushed me away. Everytime I offer him the breast he moves his face and when he has put it in his mouth, he bites me and lets go. He doesn't attempt to suck for milk. He even has refused water.

What can I do?

Comment: Try to give him things to chew on and consider a sippy cup or large-hole nipple bottle.

Comment: I did breastfeed my boy till he was 12 months. He loved the milk and wanted it all the time. I gave it to him. When he turned 13 month's everything changed. He stopped by himself, didn't want to look at it. It was very funny, since I drink a lot of water he started copying me and loved drinking water as well, I tried giving him the toddler prescribed milk(Similac ) he refused, he only has it when feeding, I didn't bother. So maybe they get tired of the milk. So if he's eating well just make sure to give him some fluids when feeding.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a nursing strike. Your baby will be ok, really. Likely his mouth hurts from teething right now, which has made him bite and he'll be back to normal soon.

One idea is to try offering when he's sleepy/asleep, since then he's more likely to follow his natural instincts to nurse.